# Why does this code make the VC++ compiler crash?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm using the following compiler:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

The following code crashes the compiler when it's compiled:

```
template<class T_> 
void crasher(T_ a, decltype(*a)* dummy = 0){}

int main()
{
    crasher(0);
    return 0;
}
```

`decltype(*a)*` used to enforce `T_` to be a pointer-like type - such as `char*`, `int*`, and `shared_ptr<int>`.

Why is it crashing? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Which version of VC++? VC++ refuses to compile this.

Comment: @sharptooth: The compiler version is: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Comment: works ok without 'decltype' ?

Comment: Why don't you send a mail to support.

Comment: This looks like something specific to VC++10 and a defect. Which means you could try http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Well spotted.  I just tried this out in 2010 and intellisense complains about the construct ("no instance of function template "crasher" matches the argument list") but when attempting to compile the source file the compiler dies.

Comment: It crashes because Microsoft does not believe in bugfixes. If you submit a bug on Connect, they'll try to run your code in the latest internal compiler snapshot, and if it works there, they'll mark it "fixed" (but they certainly won't release a fix). Otherwise, it'll be a "wontfix".

Comment: @jalf: I lol'd at your comment.

Comment: @jalf: If it still crashes on the latest internal build, they most likely will fix it, but then make you wait two years for the fix to be released in a product and charge you for it.  Not sure if that's better or worse than what you described.

Comment: @xmlinx: That's not a version, that's your serial number, and by posting it online you're violating the license agreement.  For the version, type `cl` at the Visual Studio Command Prompt, it should look something like "Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86"

Comment: If your version is in mainstream support, you could contact PSS to try to get them to create a QFE/hotfix.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your goal is

> `decltype(*a)*` used to enforce `T_` to be a pointer-like type - such as `char*`, int*, and shared_ptr.

... what you need is simple template, not a code which happens to crash the compiler :)

Here is something that may work for you

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// uncomment this "catch all" function to make select(0) compile
// int select(...){ return 0;}
template<class T>  int select(T*){ return 1;}
template<class T>  int select(std::auto_ptr<T>){ return 1;}
// add boost::shared_ptr etc, as necessary

int main()
{
    std::cout << select(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << select(std::auto_ptr<int>()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << select(&std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template isn't valid for the instantination of `T_=int` because prefix `operator*` is a substitution failure, so it should fail in some way, although without crashing of course.

Answer (score 0):

I just dont understand why you write decltype(*a)* instead of decltype(a). Since 0(zero) is int by default, then the expression decltype(a) will be int as well. If you want var dummy be a pointer to decltype(a), then you have to write decltype(a)*. This way, dummy will be of type int*. You have also to consider type conversions. 0 can convert to int*. Not sure it works for all types .